# to take values of checkbox in table attributes

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database  patient with 3-4 tables n each table has about 8 attributes....
i have a table medical history which has attribute additional info ... under which i have 5 checkboxes....
all the values entered are taken up except the chekbox values.....
plz help

Comment: I'm a bit lost. Can you state the question a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

How are you constructing your  fields? Do they all have the same `name` attribute? Do they have a name attribute at all? Is there a `value` attribute?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="testfield" value="somevalue" />
<input type="checkbox" name="testfield" value="othervalue" />
```

If you're constructing the checkboxes like that, then PHP will by default ignore all but the last value submitted (it overwrites previous values with new ones), like this:

```
$_POST = array(
   'testfield' => 'othervalue'
)
```

You have to force PHP into 'array mode' for this type of construct, by adding `[]` to the `name` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="testfield[]" value="somevalue" />
<input type="checkbox" name="testfield[]" value="othervalue" />
```

This will allow multiple values to be submitted under the same name, and you'll end up with an array in your _GET/_POST arrays:

```
$_POST = array(
   'testfield' => array('somevalue', 'othervalue')
)
```

Of course, only the checkboxes which are actually checked will be sent with the form data.

Check that your form is properly constructed by putting a `var_dump($_POST);` (or GET or REQUEST) in the form handling part of the script and see if the checkbox values are actually being sent. Perhaps you're looking for the wrong name attribute, the tags could be malformed in the form, etc...